# Laravel 5.3 with Passport: Get Current User with Personal Access Token

Tags: php, api, laravel-5, laravel-passport

I've installed Passport with Laravel 5.3 and configured to use Personal Access Token. I am sending username and password to `/oauth/token' route and get a token. Everything is fine until here.

But if I want to get current logged in user with `$user = Auth::user();` as we used to get it before, I get `null` value as Laravel don't keep any session for API Token. In this situation, how can I get the current user? Can I modify any file to get the current user along with token?

Thanks In Advance Arif

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I'm using Passport with password_clients in an OAuth2 flow.  My Lumen/Laravel version in composer is 5.4.*

I'm using the following statement in my Lumen application (note I'm not using facades):

`$user = app('auth')->guard()->user()`

This is probably equivalent to the facade call:

`$user = Auth::guard()->user()`

Hope this helps..

Kind regards,

PS. To figure what class is returned when not using facades, I find myself doing eg. a `echo get_class(app('auth'))` to get the class and tell my IDE what kind of variable `$auth` is..

Snippet from one of my Lumen controllers

```
$auth = app('auth');
// echo get_class($auth); to get class
// -> \Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager in this case
/* @var $auth \Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager */

$guard = $auth->guard();
// idem as above
/* @var $guard \Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard */

$user = $guard->user();
/* @var $auth \App\Auth\User */

// this tells Webstorm/Netbeans/.. to consider $auth an instance of AuthManager and enables autocompletion of class methods
```